# Wp-admin dashboard not working after website migration to another hosting

Tags: php, wordpress

I have migrated my wordpress site from one hosting to another by copying sites files and creating new database. I have correctly updated the database information the the wp-config.php file and the site is running smooth. However i cannot log in in the admin panel. It shows the admin login username and password page but after i submit login it shows the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_site_transient() in /home/content/XXXX/XXXX.com/XXX/wp-includes/update.php on line 466
```

Help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure your versions of PHP are up to date on the new server?

Comment: yes the versions of PHP are same

Comment: did you copy the `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Can you check if this file exists `wp-includes/option.php` ?

Comment: @doublesharp : yes i copied .htaccess file. If i didn't copied the .htaccess file then the website is not working.

Comment: @CGeorges : yes file wp-includes/option.php exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should try by re-uploading your wordpress core files.
It means that all files (except wp-content folder , wp-config file) needs to be replaced
with files  from a fresh WordPress install.
This will NOT remove any of your information, but it may solve the problem in case any file was corrupted.

**Make sure to back-up your data in case of emergency.**